# Unbelievable difference in SQL query run time between local DB and production

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have the next query:

```
SELECT `real_estates`.*
FROM `real_estates`
WHERE (photos_count > 0) AND
      (price > 0) AND
      (longitude is not null AND latitude is not null) AND
      `real_estates`.`rent` = 0 AND
      (estate_type = 0 or estate_type = 1) AND
      (price > 1000)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

DB is MySQL. Number of rows in `real_estates` table is 200k approx on production DB and local. But on development machine it takes 0.5s to run this query when production gives me 25s(!) wait time.

Table engine is InnoDB, `EXPLAIN` gives the same results on both systems. If I remove ORDER BY RAND(), it takes normal run time on prod. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps something else is running on the production server that is slowing it down.  Even without indexes on a slow server, the query should not be taking 25 seconds on 200k rows -- unless the rows are really really big.

Comment: Both systems have the same indexes

Comment: And it doesn't taking 25s on local DB with the same data, it takes 25s only on production. That's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your query, it looks like you are trying to retrieve a randomly chosen row from your `real_estates` table. The way your query is written, the MySQL server must load all the matching rows into a RAM, or maybe a hard drive, data structure and then sort them, take the first one, and discard the rest. It's very possible your shared production server has a much smaller amount of available RAM, slower disk drives, lots of other users, or all three. That means a RAM-intensive task like yours may be forced to go to disk. That slows it down. A lot. You already know that.

You might consider this refactoring of your query.

```
SELECT `real_estates`.*
FROM `real_estates`
JOIN (
        SELECT id
          FROM real_estates
         WHERE (photos_count > 0) AND
               (price > 0) AND
               (longitude is not null AND latitude is not null) AND
               `real_estates`.`rent` = 0 AND
               (estate_type = 0 or estate_type = 1) AND
               (price > 1000)
         ORDER BY RAND()
         LIMIT 1
      ) r ON real_estates.id = r.id
```

(I guess your table has a unique `id` value for each row. I'm also guessing it is called `id`. You may need to change this query to match the actual name of your id. )

The inner query contains your selection logic. But rather than producing a whole bunch of data to sort, it produces only the `id` values. It then randomly orders them and takes the first one. Finally, the join grabs the whole chosen row.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY RAND() is bad solution. Your indexes are ignored. Particularly difficult situation with large amounts of data.

You can use primary key insted of RAND().

Comment: What do you mean by use primary key? How it give me a random row? Anyway, it's not a bad solution for non-million rows table. It takes 0.5s in normal case.

Comment: `order by rand()` means that on each query mysql has to full-scan the table, then sort it. Now, the recordset likely doesn't fit into sort buffer, so mysql has to write it to a file and sort the file instead. Lots of overhead.

Comment: Perhaps sort buffer settings are different between dev and prod envs.